# Number in occurrence of some variable(s) in SQL

Tags: sql

I would like to add a column to a SQL Table with the number in occurrence of some variable(s).
For example:

| id | date |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | 2021-09-10 |
| 01 | 2021-12-25 |
| 01 | 2022-02-01 |
| 02 | 2016-03-25 |
| 02 | 2017-11-03 |

So the table is already ordered by id and date.
I would like to get a column "nbr_of_occurrence"

| id | date | nbr_of_occurrence |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 2021-09-10 | 1 |
| 01 | 2021-12-25 | 2 |
| 01 | 2022-02-01 | 3 |
| 02 | 2016-03-25 | 1 |
| 02 | 2017-11-03 | 2 |

So in this example I only want to count the number of times "ID" occurs.

Can someone please give me some tip?

Comment: I presume you would like to count the number of times `ID` occurs *before each date*?

Comment: The answer can vary depending on database version.  What RDBMS are you using and what version?  Most current RDBMS can use an analytical function or window function to solve this.  However older versions or some personal RDBMS do not have these features.

Answer (score 2):

most dbms support row_number()

```
select id,date,row_number()over(partition by id order by date) orc
from table_name
```